# Can't install Python modules in Gitlab CI

Tags: python, gitlab, continuous-integration, gstreamer

I can't get Gst (or seemingly any Python module) to install inside Gitlab CI

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - apt-get -qq update
  - apt-get -qq install -y python3-dev python3-pip libgirepository1.0-dev 
  - python3 --version
  - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  
test:
  script:
    - pip3 install flake8  # you can also use tox
    - flake8 --max-line-length=254 --extend-ignore=F401,E402 matinee.py

run:
  script:
    - ./matinee.py -h
```

But no matter what I tried the closest I got to was:

```
$ ./matinee.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./matinee.py", line 6, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 126, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gst not available
```

Before that it complained that `gi` didn't exist (?) so basically it seems like python modules are not installable this way.

It's been a week now, and frankly I'm giving up on setting up Gitlab CI for python ; I have nodejs projects with tons of deps passing installing without a glitch ; This post is my last hail Mary attempt :|

Naturally, everything works perfectly locally (Ubuntu 22)

My requirements file

```
# cat requirements.txt 
PyGObject==3.42.1
```

What I tried

```
image: "python:3.7"
image: "python:latest"
image: "ubuntu:latest"
venv
```

And everything on [this page](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devguide/dev_environ.html#devenv). Please, help me understand why I can't install Python modules in Gitlab CI.

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing `python3 -m pip`, `pip3` and `pip`?

Comment: My bad, it's just a typo, I tried so many things :) the pipeline just failed again just now.

Comment: What about `python3 matinee.py -h`?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Oh, but it works, the only thing is I can't get the *basic* libraries to install **and** make themselves known, so it breaks immediately at the first import ; Hence my question.

Comment: Yeah I’m saying call the script with `python3` explicitly rather than `./`. You (definitely) have more than one version of python installed - that’s probably the rough transition you’re not used to from npm. Especially with docker, being explicit about your python versions is a good idea because you can’t always rely on the python version you just installed to be the first one on PATH